# Hierarchical Vaadin Tree from XML(MSDL)

Tags: java, xml, tree, vaadin

im tryind to build an Vaadin tree from an XML file(MSDL), im stuck at adding child items to my tree. So far i can read from my XML file and display the the tags/info i want but i cant make an  Hierarchical  strukture out of it , e.g :

i have an XML file with some information about Planets and their moons and the galaxy they are in :

```
Milky Way
 -Sunsystem
  -Earth
   -"Moon"
  -Mars
    -Phobos
    -Deimos
  -Saturn
    -Titan
    -Tethys
Pinwheel Galaxy
 -somesystem
   -weirdPlanet1
     -moon1
     -moon2
   -weirdPlanet2
     -moon1
     -moon2
```

now i want to have the same strukture in my vaadin tree. i have tryed lots of things but the result was always the same : some null values where added to the tree of i could see only the galaxys but i couldnt expand them or i could see a tree with all the infos but there whee no strukture at all all planets / moons where just listed :/

Comment: How do you add the data from the XML file into the tree?

Comment: I have writen my own MSDLHandler class that gets the xml file and adds it to the three (java.util.Stack (ContentHandler)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this doesn't have anything to do with the Tree itself. Instead of adding the data directly to the Tree, you can try this:

1. Parse the XML data into a [HierarchicalContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/HierarchicalContainer.html)
2. Iterate through the HierarchicalContainer with the sample code below and verify that it's identical to your XML file structure
3. Bind the data container to the tree by calling [Tree.setContainerDataSource(Container)](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Tree.html#setContainerDataSource%28com.vaadin.data.Container%29)

Sample code to iterate through a HierarchicalContainer:

```
void iterateContainer() {
    for(Object rootItemId : myContainer.rootItemIds()) {
        Item rootItem = myContainer.getItem(rootItemId);
        System.out.println(rootItem.getItemProperty(myLabelProperty).getValue());

        iterateChildren(rootItemId, 1);
    }
}

void iterateChildren(Object parentItemId, int indent) {

    for(Object childItemId : myContainer.getChildren(parentItemId)) {
        Item childItem = myContainer.getItem(childItemId);

        for(int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(childItem.getItemProperty(myLabelProperty).getValue());

        if(myContainer.hasChildren(childItemId)) {
            iterateChildren(childItemId, indent+1);
        }
    }

}
```

This is just some untested QnD code, but this should help you to iterate through the container.

edit: Just noticed that my answer could have been (partially) a stupid solution, since Tree already utilizes HierarchicalContainer. You can initialize myContainer `HierarchicalContainer myContainer = (HierarchicalContainer) myTree.getContainerDataSource();` and use the code above.

edit2: And if the structure isn't identical, see where it goes wrong and let the debugger do the rest .. :)